# Random Number Generated from File Input

Tags: c#

I am new to programming in C# and I'm having problems generating random numbers from input read form a file. I am trying to generate random numbers from the second field on each line from the following input read from a text file

```
4321,99
5432,79
6543,59
7654,39
```

The file is read by the following code, then parsed into separate fields where a method is called to generate a random number

```
    private void readFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string readString;
        inputFile = File.OpenText(sourceFileString);

        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            readString = inputFile.ReadLine();
            var flds = readString.Split(',');

            string patID = flds[0];
            int months = Convert.ToInt32(flds[1]);

            Random();
        }
        inputFile.Close();
    }
```

The method I am using that generates a random number from the second field

```
    private void Random()
    {
        Random rand2Integer = new Random();
        randomInteger = rand2Integer.Next(1, months) + 1;
    }
```

However, this exception is thrown: 'minValue' cannot be greater than maxValue, and I can't wrap my head around it. If I manually enter the data on a form using a text box then the random number is generated as expected. Any input to guide me along?

Comment: what is the value of months here?? the error says it is less than 1

Comment: @Rex: it should be the value after the comma of the line read from the file.

Comment: @User3457978: Does your file by any chance contains a line where the second value is less than 1?

Comment: i think @Rex refers to the variable months in the Random method, not the one in your button click

Comment: @failedprogramming: indeed, and since that takes the value of an (uninitialized) field, it is probably zero...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your code it looks like you have a class variable **months**. However, while reading file you have declared a local variable which essentially hides the class variable.

Now when you use Random function, the class variable is used (which must have 0 and causing this error)

replace the following line of code

```
int months = Convert.ToInt32(flds[1]);
```

with

```
months = Convert.ToInt32(flds[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable `months` in `Random()` is not the same that the one you are assigning in `int months = Convert.ToInt32(flds[1]);` the last is local to the method.

You should define `month` outside or pass it as a parameter to `Random()`

**EDIT:**
I made minor changes to make code easier to read. Hope it helps.

```
private void readFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // If you use the stream this way it will be disposed automatically.
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(sourceFileString))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string readString = sr.ReadLine();
            var flds = readString.Split(',');

            string patID = flds[0];

            int months = int.Parse(flds[1]);

            //I prefer parameters more than fields to communicate between methods.
            Random(months);
        }

    }
}

Random randomGenerator = new Random();

private void Random(int months)
{
    randomInteger = randomGenerator.Next(1, months) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `readFile` function, you declare a variable called `months` and initialize it to the number from your file. This appears correct and probably works great.

However, that variable has **function** scope. You likely have another variable called "months" at the class level (otherwise you would be getting a compile time error). This variable, and not the one set in "readFile", is what is used by the "Random" method. Change the line to:

```
months = Convert.ToInt32(flds[1]);
```

and it will work.

As an aside, you should not use a new instance of `Random` every time you need a draw. It is considered better practice to have one instance per object and reuse it each time you need a new random number.